# Why is there a difference in the power usage of the accelerometer vs. the gravity sensor?

Tags: android, accelerometer

On my android device (Nexus 5) the [getPower()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getPower%28%29) method returns a value of 0.45mA for the acclerometer and 3.65mA for the gravity sensor.

My understanding was that the gravity sensor was simply a virtual sensor that ran the accelerometer data through a filter. If so, why does it draw more power?

Is the value returned for getPower() even accurate or related to actual power consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that the gravity sensor was simply a virtual sensor that ran the
>   accelerometer data through a filter.

Nope. The virtual gravity sensor fuses the accelerometer, gyroscopes and the magnetometer (compass) readings and not only the accelerometer readings. I guess the biggest consumer is the magnetometer.

Answer (score 1):

`Acceleration sensor` gives you back the sum of all forces applied to your device, while `Gravity sensor` returns only the influence of gravity. That's why you are getting more power for `acclerometer` than `the gravity sensor`. you can refer the doc for [Using the Accelerometer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel) and for [Using the Gravity Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-grav) Please look at [Which Sensors in Android gets Direct Input? What are Virtual Sensors?](http://www.sensorplatforms.com/which-sensors-in-android-gets-direct-input-what-are-virtual-sensors/) for more clarification.

from the doc it says

**Note:** When a device is at rest, the output of the gravity sensor should be identical to that of the accelerometer.